# D3 geo node plotting on map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geolocation, geometry, maps

I've recently created this D3 map which I had intended to put nodes on the map with links between each node. However I don't know how to do this without using force layout. So far I have created a map of the world using d3 geo map. I have seen a couple of examples of the lines e.g. http://datamaps.github.io/old.html but these don't have nodes on the end of them. I've put my version on JSFiddle which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/GarrettUK/n396w4vq/2/.

**I'm sure the way to do the lines would be like this:**

```
var election = new Datamap({
        scope: 'world',
        element: document.getElementById('arcs'),
        projection: 'mercator'
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you back to the Data Maps arc tutorial.

http://datamaps.github.io/

As far a creating nodes, you could always just append an image to your map using the d3.append and then decide what attributes if any to assign those images. If your looking for the classic node, just append a circle by doing something like this.

```
var img = g.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "circle")
```

Comment: I can't seem to get these working, can you show me in the JSFiddle please?